# Thumbs up/ Thumbs down rating implementation using Rating class

Tags: java, android, rating-system

In my media player app (Android based), I want to implement a Thumbs Up/ Thumbs Down rating system. Now, since the framework provides a default [`android.media.Rating`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Rating.html) class to handle different types of ratings, I was figuring out a way to implement Thumbs based rating using the `Rating` class.

I have written the following methods to set either Up, Down or Unrated rating.

```
MediaMetadataCompat metadata; // initial metadata

public void setLiked() {
    RatingCompat likedRating = RatingCompat.newThumbRating(true);

    metadata = new MediaMetadataCompat
            .Builder(metadata)
            .putRating(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_USER_RATING, likedRating)
            .build();
}

public void setDisliked() {
    RatingCompat dislikedRating = RatingCompat.newThumbRating(false);

    metadata = new MediaMetadataCompat
            .Builder(metadata)
            .putRating(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_USER_RATING, dislikedRating)
            .build();
}

public void setUnrated() {
    RatingCompat unratedRating = RatingCompat.newUnratedRating(RatingCompat.RATING_NONE);

    metadata = new MediaMetadataCompat
            .Builder(metadata)
            .putRating(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_USER_RATING, unratedRating)
            .build();
}
```

Although I haven't tested the methods, since the both app and the module hasn't been finished yet. Is it the right way to apply rating to a song? Also I can't find a way to retrieve the ratings back.

I've rolled through the documentation numerous times without getting much clue; and any examples available online are only based on star based rating. If someone has experience implementing Thumbs based rating in Android using Ratings class, help me out here. Thanks.

### TLDR

To make this question not too specific, I'm offering a more generalized explanation so that this question will be more helpful for other people in future.
Basically, I want an explanation/example for the Rating class in context of Thumbs based rating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation seems correct to me, you can retrieve ratings with this method:

```
metadata = new MediaMetadataCompat
            .Builder(metadata).build();
RatingCompat rating = metadata.getRating(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_USER_RATING);
//you can use rating.isRated() for getting is set or not
//you can use rating.isThumbUp() for getting boolean value
```

Comment: So, a thumbs down would result in `rating.isThumbUp()` to return a `false`?

Comment: Function description is as follow: 
* @return true if the rating is "thumb up", false if the rating is "thumb down",
     *    if the rating style is not {@link #RATING_THUMB_UP_DOWN} or if it is unrated.

So yes :)

Comment: Oh! It was right there! How come I missed it! Thanks. I will accept this answer after trying out the code.

Answer (score 0):

If I would write your code above I would do it like this:

```
MediaMetadataCompat metadata; // initial metadata

public void setLiked(boolean liked) {
    buildMetaFor(RatingCompat.newThumbRating(liked));
}

public void setUnrated() {
    buildMetaFor(RatingCompat.newUnratedRating(RatingCompat.RATING_NONE));
}

public RatingCompat getRating() {
    return metadata.getRating(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_USER_RATING);
}

public MediaMetadataCompat buildMetaFor(RatingCompat rating) {
    metadata = new MediaMetadataCompat
            .Builder(metadata)
            .putRating(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_USER_RATING, rating)
            .build();

    return metadata;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I would do that generally. Although I was in a hurry while asking the question, so I just copy pasted the same function right here in the browser and edited them accordingly.

Comment: I think you don't want to have "putRating()" in builder function. Your function may be more elegant if you say return new Object.Builder(object).build(); Because now, you can't use getRating directly, you will get a null pointer exception.